# Fix Error Running as root without -- no-sandbox is not supported

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, web-browsers, root

I wanna run an easy script via the terminal which opens my webbrowser and brings it in something like a kiosk-mode by pressing 'F11'. For this I installed the module keyboard for python 2 and 3 and for the root user.
I am using a new Raspberry Pi 4. 
I guess the Error has something to dowith my webbrowser, tha I'm not allowed to run it with the sudo command. But why?

Code:

`import webbrowser
import keyboard
webbrowser.open('http://10.54.45.128/', new=2) 
keyboard.press_and_release('F11')`

Command and Error-message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/startupBrowser.py
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ [3800:3800:0317/155907.642806:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
[3828:3828:0317/155908.195394:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: firefox: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
[3864:3864:0317/155908.823198:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://10.54.45.128/'
```

Thank you all for the quick help :)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the Raspberry. It's about browser security in general.